# How to show Y axis ticks for every point in the graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs to display some data but I'm in trouble with the Y axis visualization. I want at every point in the graph a value in the Y axis. Right now the Y axis display value in steps of 10.

This is my actual yAxis configuration:

```
yAxes: [{
            position: "left",
            ticks: {
                source:"data",
            } 
        }]
```

This is the actual chart. I would like to display in the Y axis only the actual value of the points displayed. In the X axis this configuration works, the time is aligned with the points. 
[image: actual]

Expected:

[image: expected]

Comment: Can't visualize your picture, try uploading it again, 'cause I'm not very sure what you looking for...

Comment: ok, check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [Axis Callbacks (docs)](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks), especially `afterBuildTicks`.

In my [linked example (jsbin)](https://jsbin.com/loyogaduso/2/edit?html,js,output) I push 0 to my data because you can't use `beginAtZero: true` and remove all the duplicates in the array.

```
data.push(0); //if 'beginAtZero' is wanted
let uniqueData = data.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
```

In the options you define the min and max values and the ticks in `afterBuildTicks`.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        autoSkip: false,
        min: Math.min(...uniqueData),
        max: Math.max(...uniqueData)
      },
      afterBuildTicks: function(scale) {
        scale.ticks = uniqueData;
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

You will have problems with overlapping ticks but I don't know a general way to prevent that and I don't know your specific use case.